# Grouping in SQL Server plus by multiple parameters and joining results by a parameter

Tags: sql-server

I couldn't come up with a better title.

I have a table with this structure:

`id | timestamp | barcode`

I need to get the count for each product for each day and shift with one query.

`Product` is `left(barcode, 9)`, `date` should come from the `timestamp`, which is `datetime` and `shift` should come from timestamp as well. Shifts are as follows:

```
Shift 1 : 06:00:00 to 14:29:59
Shift 2 : 14:30:00 to 22:59:59
Shift 3 : 23:00:00 to 05:59:59
```

So I basically need a result like:

```
date       | shift | item number | count
12.02.2019 | 1     | 827384950   | 32
```

So Far I have this:

```
select cast(timestamp as date) as date,
   (case when convert(time, timestamp) >= '06:00:00' and
              convert(time, timestamp) < '14:30:00'
         then 1
         when convert(time, timestamp) >= '14:30:00' and
              convert(time, timestamp) < '23:00:00'
         then 2
         else 3
    end) as shift,
   left(barcode, 9) as item_number,
   count(*)
from t
group by cast(timestamp as date),
     (case when convert(time, timestamp) >= '06:00:00' and
                convert(time, timestamp) < '14:30:00'
           then 1
           when convert(time, timestamp) >= '14:30:00' and
                convert(time, timestamp) < '23:00:00'
           then 2
           else 3
      end),
     left(barcode, 9)
order by date, shift, item_number;
```

It does the job, but the problem is this:

Shift 3 is actually taking part in two days, since it is from 23:00 on one day until 6 on the next day. This code splits shift 3 to two parts - one for each day.

I need to group it so Shift 3 shows for the day it started and then counts it's item count until it finishes on the next day.

Answer (score 3):

I like to keep complicated logic out of `GROUP BY` clauses, this way when someone else comes to read the code they can clearly grasp the logic of the grouping. I instead separate out the logic into a `SELECT` statement of a CTE, and use the resulting columns in a simple readable query.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT id, LEFT(barcode, 9) item_number,
        CONVERT(DATE, CASE WHEN CONVERT(TIME, timestamp) <'06:00:00' THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, timestamp) ELSE timestamp END) AS date,
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(TIME, timestamp) >= '06:00:00' AND
          CONVERT(TIME, timestamp) < '14:30:00'
             THEN 1
             WHEN CONVERT(TIME, timestamp) >= '14:30:00' AND
                  CONVERT(TIME, timestamp) < '23:00:00'
             THEN 2
             ELSE 3
        END AS shift 
    FROM Table t
)

SELECT date, shift, item_number, count(*) as count
FROM cte
GROUP BY date, shift, item_number
```

Comment: Good call on the CTE - makes it much cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.shift = 3 AND a.[time] < '06:00' THEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,a.[date]) ELSE a.[date] END AS [date]
    ,a.shift,a.item_number,COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATE,t.[timestamp]) AS [date]
        ,TRY_CONVERT(TIME,t.timestamp) AS [time]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN TRY_CONVERT(TIME,t.timestamp) >= '23:00' OR TRY_CONVERT(TIME,t.timestamp) < '06:00' THEN 3
            WHEN TRY_CONVERT(TIME,t.timestamp) >= '14:30' THEN 2
            ELSE 1
        END AS [shift]
        ,LEFT(t.barcode,9) AS [item_number]
    FROM [YourTableName] t
) a
GROUP BY CASE WHEN a.shift = 3 AND a.[time] < '06:00' THEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,a.[date]) ELSE a.[date] END
    ,a.shift,a.item_number
;
```

Comment: This produces a result in which every day has multiple Shift 1, Shift 2 and Shift 3s. I added an `order by date` at the end, could it be the reason?

Comment: Could you please provide sample data

Answer (score 0):

If you have some sample data to test with, that would be great!

Essentially, I am shifting the timestamp back 6 hours to avoid the confusion of the cross-day 3rd shift. It pulls the full 3rd shift to the date in which the shift starts while not losing the date of the 1st shift (since 00:00 counts for the date).

```
SELECT TheDay = TRY_CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, t.[timestamp])),
       Shift = CASE 
                 WHEN TRY_CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, t.[timestamp])) < '08:30'
                   THEN 1
                 WHEN TRY_CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, t.[timestamp])) < '17:00'
                   THEN 2
                 ELSE 3
               END,
      Product = LEFT(t.[barcode], 9),
      ItemCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM [TableName] t
 GROUP BY TRY_CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, t.[timestamp])), 
          CASE 
             WHEN TRY_CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, t.[timestamp])) < '08:30'
               THEN 1
             WHEN TRY_CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, t.[timestamp])) < '17:00'
               THEN 2
             ELSE 3
          END,
          LEFT(t.[barcode], 9)
```

@elizabk makes a good point:

```
;WITH shiftedData (TheDay, Shift, Product) AS (
    SELECT TheDay = TRY_CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, t.[timestamp])),
           Shift = CASE 
                     WHEN TRY_CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, t.[timestamp])) < '08:30'
                        THEN 1
                     WHEN TRY_CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, t.[timestamp])) < '17:00'
                        THEN 2
                     ELSE 3
                   END,
          Product = LEFT(t.[barcode], 9)
      FROM [TableName] t
)
SELECT TheDay, Shift, Product, ProductCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM shiftedData
 GROUP BY TheDay, Shift, Product
```